# Keyboard button get pressed forever

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I have a brand new hp original windows 10, bought it few month ago, the keyboard looks perfect. I have an issue, starting from today, the `-` keyboard button get pressed forever, kinda link it's stuck down but it's not.

When I restart the PC, or logout and in, it works normally again, but in an hour or so, it will get stuck down. I have malwarebyte and windows defender, no virus detected. Is there a way to check if this issue is caused by a software or a driver malfunction? Otherwise I'm gonna send it to the shop and use my guarantee to fix it or get another one.

Comment: What's the model?

Comment: Did you try cleaning under the key?

Comment: @Moses HP Notebook - 14-ac016ne (ENERGY STAR)

Comment: Use your warranty. Call HP support and let them troubleshoot it. You paid for it.

Comment: @DavidPostill i dont see anything, plus last time i tried to clean my keyboard on my other hp, i ruined it so im kinda hesitating to do so

Comment: @CharlieRB yes i agree, if it's not a software issue, i will do that

Comment: Boot to an Ubuntu Live CD to see if it still has the same issue. If it does, then it is a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy to disconnect and remove most laptop keyboards. Most manufacturer's have a user service guide available online that shows you how to do so. Disconnect the keyboard's ribbon cable, and power up the notebook.

If the issue is still there (it likely is not), then the problem is physical. There is either a foreign object underneath the key, or dirt. In your case, since the notebook is only a few months old, it's probably a foreign object or the key might not have been inserted/attached correctly during manufacturing.

If you can't figure out which of those is the cause, a replacement keyboard might run you $20-30 and replacing it is almost always a breeze. Repair at a shop might run you double that, depending on where you live. Replacing the key itself is also an option, but in my experience it requires patience, which...I don't have!

Comment: This would void the warranty in most cases.

Comment: @CharlieRB Isn't the keyboard a user-serviceable item in most cases?

Comment: @CharlieRB Ah, according to this model's service guide, it is not. You are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like hardware. Every time I've had something like this happen, it's been dirty or malfunctioning hardware.
Next time this happens, you can try pressing the "-" key, to see if that gets it unstuck.